# StaticLayout hyphenation broken when using a subclass of TextPaint

Tags: java, android

I'm finding that in my custom view which uses a `StaticLayout`, the hyphenation breaks if I use a subclass of `TextPaint` instead of `TextPaint` itself.

My custom view:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    String mText = "Using TextPaint: Recommendations";
    TextPaint mTextPaint;
    StaticLayout mStaticLayout;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint2();    // Works fine with TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = Math.round(100 * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));

        StaticLayout.Builder builder = StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(mText, 0, mText.length(), mTextPaint, width)
                 .setHyphenationFrequency(Layout.HYPHENATION_FREQUENCY_FULL);
        mStaticLayout = builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
        mStaticLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

My subclass of `TextPaint`:

```
public class TextPaint2 extends TextPaint {
    // Doesn't override anything
}
```

Does anyone know what's happening here? Is this a bug and if so, is there a workaround to this?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot Example]